# If $X_{n} \to X$ and $Y_{n} \to Y$ in probability, then $f(X_{n},Y_{n}) \to f(X,Y)$ in probability for $f$ continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, weak-convergence, bivariate-distributions

For a bivariate, real continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, I need to show that $f(X_{n},Y_{n}) \to f(X,Y)$ in probability whenever $X_{n} \to X$ and $Y_{n}\to Y$ in probability.

This is essentially a bivariate version of the Continuous Mapping Theorem for convergence in probability, and so my attempt involves essentially just copying the proof for the univariate case. **What I don't realize, however, is if there are any nuances that should creep into this anywhere because all we are given is that $X_{n} \to X$ and $Y_{n} \to Y$ in probability, and not that $(X_{n},Y_{n}) \to (X,Y)$ in probability (although, by convergence of vectors, it makes sense that we would be guaranteed this).**

Anyway, here is what I did:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, for any $K \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}$, $$P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon)\\ \leq P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon, \, |(X,Y)|\leq K, \, |(X_{n},Y_{n})|\leq K) + P(\{ |X,Y|>K\} \cup \{|X_{n},Y_{n}|>K\}) $$
>
> We note that since $\{(x,y):|(x,y)\leq K\}$ is a compact set, $f$ is uniformly continuous there.
>
> Therefore, $\exists \delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ s.t. $|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|\leq \epsilon$ for $|(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|<\delta$ (where we consider the set where $|(X,Y)|\leq K$ and $|(X_{n},Y_{n})|\leq K$). And so, $$ \{|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon, \, |(X,Y)|\leq K, \, |(X_{n},Y_{n})|\leq K \} \subseteq \{ |(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\delta \} $$
>   Thus, we have $$ P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon) \leq P(|(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\delta) + P(|(X,Y)|>K)+P(|(X_{n},Y_{n})|>K) \\ \leq P(|(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\delta) + P(|(X,Y)>K) + P\left(|(X,Y)|>\frac{K}{2}\right) + P\left( |(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\frac{K}{2}\right)$$
>
> Now, let $\gamma > 0$ be arbitrary, and then we can choose $K$ sufficiently large such that the second and third terms in the last inequality are both less than $\gamma/2$.
>
> Thus, we have, for sufficiently large $K$, $\displaystyle P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon) \leq P(|(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\delta) + P\left(|(X_{n},Y_{n})-(X,Y)|>\frac{K}{2}\right)+ \gamma.$
>
> Finally, taking the limit of both sides of this equation and using the fact that $X_{n}-X \to^{P}0$ and $Y_{n}-Y \to^{P} 0$, we have that $P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y)|>\epsilon) \leq \gamma$, and since $\gamma > 0$ was arbitrary, we have $f(X_{n},Y_{n})-f(X,Y) \to^{P} 0$, as desired.

**Is this a correct proof to show that $X_{n} \to X$ and $Y_{n} \to Y$ in probability implies that $f(X_{n},Y_{n}) \to f(X,Y)$ in probability? If not, then what would be a correct proof?** Thank you ahead of time for your time and patience!

---

**UPDATE**: As this proof stands, I believe it is incomplete. What I think I need to complete it is a proof of the result that says that the vector $(X_{n},Y_{n}) \to (X,Y)$ in probability if and only if $X_{n} \to X$ in probability and $Y_{n} \to Y$ in probability. **Could someone please help me prove this?** I think that once I have that, everything else I did here will be okay (please correct me if I'm wrong!) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to your more specific question**

One way is obvious since $$P(d(X_n,X) < \epsilon) \ge P(d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y)) <\epsilon) \to 1.$$ (because if $d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y)) <\epsilon$ then it follows that $d(X_n,X) < \epsilon$.)

For the other way, note that by triangle, $$d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y))\le d(X_n,X) + d(Y_n,Y)$$ so that if $d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y))> \epsilon$ it follows that one of  $d(X_n,X)$ or $d(Y_n,Y)$ needs to be greater than $\epsilon/2$ (actually greater than $\epsilon/\sqrt 2$ for Euclidean distance, but it doesn't really matter). So $$ P(d((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y)) >\epsilon)  \le P((d(X_n,X) >\epsilon/2)\cup (d(Y_n,Y) >\epsilon/2)) \\\le P(d(X_n,X) >\epsilon/2) + P(d(Y_n,Y) >\epsilon/2) \to 0$$

Comment: thank you for your help! Do you think that this result combined with what I had done above is enough to get the job done?

Comment: @ALannister Don't have time to go through your above now, but my guess would be that combining this with the trick to deal with non-uniform continuity from the one-variable case should work straightforwardly, and it looks like that's what your approach was.

Answer (score 3):

Lemma: Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of random variables in a probability
space and let $X$ be a random variable. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in probability,

(b) Any subsequence of $\{X_{n}\}$ has a subsequence that converges
to $X$ in probability.

Proof: $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ is obvious.

$(b)\Rightarrow(a)$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary
that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x_{n}:=P\left([|X_{n}-X|\geq\delta]\right)$
does not converge to $0$. Then $\{x_{n}\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$
that is bounded away from $0$. That is, there exists $\epsilon>0$
and a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $x_{n_{k}}\geq\epsilon$
for all $k$. Clearly $\{X_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ does not have a subsequence
that converges to $X$ in probability, contradicting to the assumption (b).

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

For your problem: Let $f(X_{n_{k}},Y_{n_{k}})_{k}$ be an arbitrary
subsequence of $f(X_{n},Y_{n})_{n}$. Note that $X_{n_{k}}\rightarrow X$
in probability, so $\{X_{n_{k}}\}_k$ has a subsequence $\{X_{n_{k_{l}}}\}_{l}$
that converges pointwisely to $X$ $P-a.e.$ (a result due to Vitali).
$Y_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow Y$ in probability as $l\rightarrow\infty$,
so it has a subsequence $\{Y_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}}\}_{j}$ that converges
to $Y$ pointwisely $P-a.e.$ Now $X_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}}\rightarrow X$
and $Y_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}}\rightarrow Y$ pointwisely $P$-a.e. Since $f$ is continuous,
it follows that $f(X_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}},Y_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}})\rightarrow f(X,Y)$
pointwisely $P$-a.e. and hence $f(X_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}},Y_{n_{k_{l_{j}}}})\rightarrow f(X,Y)$
in probability as $j\rightarrow\infty$. By the lemma, the results
follow.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Please do not completely trust my mathematics and one should examine the above argument carefully before accepting it. As I have not played with probability theory for a long time, I may commit mistake without realizing it. Please do not hesitate and point out my mistakes if you find them.

Comment: in order to use that result at the bottom though, don't I need to prove also that a vector converges in probability if and only if each of its components converges in probability?

Comment: You need to clarity the meaning of $|(X_n,Y_n)-(X,Y)|\geq \delta$. Is $|\cdot|$ the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: absolutely. Nothing weird is going on here. We are in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and using all the usual norms and inner products therein.

Comment: well, thank you for this, but if you think it's probably not correct, but what I did above is not necessarily incorrect, without that side proof about the vectors converging in probability if and only if each component converges in probability, I'm afraid I'm no closer than I was before.